# How do i keep an app open whilst also browsing on chrome?

Tags: applications

Dumb question but...

So i'm using the app but want to research something related on the web , and switch back and forth between the two.

Thanks

Comment: Which app do you want to keep open? Are you referring to split screen view? Which phone?

Comment: Hello, Just a Samsung phone. Just want to view between the app and browsing the web.

Comment: If the other app is closing while you are browsing the web with Chrome, it is quite likely that you do not have sufficient resources (ie. RAM) to keep both applications in memory at one time and switch between them... To keep the user experience acceptable, the Android kernel is forcing one of the application to close while it is in the background to free up memory for the active application. This is an indication either you do not have the proper hardware for your needs (insufficient RAM and/or processing power) or your browser is just using excessive resources (ie. too many tabs open).

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the button that brings up all your applications. It's usually the one on the right hand side. Then once you see the app you're using on half of the screen you can either select the browser from the running apps selection that is listed on the other half of the screen if it is running, or press the home button in the center and select your browser that way. If done correctly you should bring up your browser and whatever app using simultaneously.